# Recovering all content from JSON array

Tags: php, json, url

Given an array:

```
{"aaData":[
    {"first":2, "second":"4", "third":"5"},
    {"first":4, "second":"56", "third":"67"}
    {"first":3, "second":"55", "third":"8"}],
 "sEcho":1, "iTotalRecords":1, "iTotalDisplayRecords":1}
```

When I  read and return it:

```
$json_string = 'my_url';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata);
return array('sEcho'=> 1, 
       'iTotalRecords'=> 5, 
       'iTotalDisplayRecords'=> 5, 
       'aaData'=>array(
                     array($obj->aaData[0]->first, 
                         $obj->aaData[0]->second,
                         $obj->aaData[0]->third)
                 )
        );
```

I get only the first item in `aaData`: `{"first":2,"second":"4","third":"5"}`

But I need to get all content from `my_url`. how i can do it?

Comment: You use a loop ([`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) to iterate over the array.

Comment: when i use foreach a had {Array,Array,Array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already trying to print only first array value by specifying `$obj->aaData[0]`.

You have to use below code to get all the values.

```
return array('sEcho'=> 1,
             'iTotalRecords'=> 5,
             'iTotalDisplayRecords'=> 5,
             'aaData'=>array(array($obj->aaData)));
```

Comment: thank you it's work ! but now when i output this content a have ([object, Object],[object Object])

Comment: drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery("#example").dataTable({"bProcessing": true,"bServerSide": true,"sAjaxSource": "../fancystuff/json"});});', 'inline');

Comment: "fancystuff/json" is my page with all the values